# How can the BBC micro:bit's scrolling display be slowed down?

Tags: bbc-microbit

I am trying to give a BBC micro:bit to grandchildren and am learning how to use with the unit MicroPython, maybe also Javascript and MakeCode.

I have a problem viewing error messages on the micro:bit's small 5x5 LED screen due to scroll speed.

Is there a way to slow down the scroll and how?

Comment: Thank you for thed advice.

Of course I looked at that Website - in fact am using it for trying Micropython programs. . Didn't find there a solution.

Scroll spead for Micropython, Javascript, etc. errors detected during lashing and maybe in general is probably controlled by built-in the program running the Micro:bit, not at the Micropython, etc.. level

Comment: Yes, the simulator is likely to catch errors, but it is important to be able to control display scrolling also if programs displays information when running.

Comment: `microbit.display.scroll` https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/display.html#microbit.display.scroll has a `delay` parameter which controls how fast the text is scrolling. Use this to text from your code.

Comment: Thank you! 
Glad the scroll speed can be controlled